# Python Pandas: print the csv data in oder with columns

Tags: python, pandas, printing

Hi I am new with python, I am using pandas to read the csv file data, and print it. The code is shown as following:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import codecs

from  pandas import Series, DataFrame

dframe = pd.read_csv("/home/vagrant/geonlp_japan_station.csv",sep=',',    
encoding="Shift-JIS")
print (dframe.head(2))
```

but the data is printed like as following(I just give example to show it)
  [image: printed result]

However, I want the data to be order with columns like as following:
[image: expect printing result]

I don't know how to make the printed data be clear, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [`unicode-formatting`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#unicode-formatting) and set:

```
pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)
```

I test it with `UTF-8` version [`csv`](https://geonlp.ex.nii.ac.jp/dictionary/geonlp/japan_station/geonlp_japan_station_20130912_u.zip):

```
dframe = pd.read_csv("test/geonlp_japan_station/geonlp_japan_station_20130912_u.csv")
```

and it seems align of output is better.

```
pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)
print dframe


pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', False)
print dframe
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there is the same issue, you can download the data from the following link:https://geonlp.ex.nii.ac.jp/dictionary/geonlp/japan_station                           the data file is : geonlp_japan_station_20130912_u.zip(UTF-8)
geonlp_japan_station_20130912_s.zip(Shift_JIS)