# pandas.core.config.OptionError: "No such keys(s): 'display.unicode.east_asian_width'"

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I want to make the printed result of my python code be aligned properly. 
 although I have got the suggestion by the @jezrael in the stack overflow, and added the following code:

```
 pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True).
```

Please see the question which I have posted in this site: [Python Pandas: print the csv data in oder with columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136649/python-pandas-print-the-csv-data-in-oder-with-columns/37136793#37136793)

Although it works in vagrant (python 3 version) and emac environment, but I can't work in the terminal environment (python 2 version) and the error is printed:

```
pandas.core.config.OptionError: "No such keys(s): 'display.unicode.eat_asian_width'


taka-no-MacBook-Pro:Desktop tianke0711$ python test_plot.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "test_plot.py", line 8, in <module>

    pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/config.py", line 222, in __call__

    return self.__func__(*args, **kwds)

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/config.py", line 119, in _set_option

    key = _get_single_key(k, silent)

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/config.py", line 83, in _get_single_key

    raise OptionError('No such keys(s): %r' % pat)

pandas.core.config.OptionError: "No such keys(s):

 'display.unicode.eat_asian_width'
```

I don't know how to solve it, please give me your hand, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for editing my question @LoicTheAztec. I have solved the question.

Comment: Since the python version is different. More, the different version of python have different version of pandas. The python 2.7 which I have used currently has the pandas:0.16.2, and this version of pandas has not No such keys(s): 'display.unicode.at_asian_width', and cause the error. However, the version of pandas:pandas-0.18.1 support this. Two solution, 1. use the python3 version 2. update pandas:conda install pandas=0.18.1 in python 2. But when you want to install the latest version of pandas, there is error : The following specifications were found to be in conflict:mayavi

Comment: firstly, conda uninstall mayavi, and then conda install pandas=0.18.1, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the python version is different. More, the different version of python have different version of pandas. The python 2.7 which I have used currently has the pandas:0.16.2, and this version of pandas has not No such keys(s): 'display.unicode.at_asian_width', and cause the error. However, the version of pandas:pandas-0.18.1 support this.

Two solution, 1. use the python3 version 2. update pandas:conda install pandas=0.18.1 in python 2. But when you want to install the latest version of pandas, there is error : The following specifications were found to be in conflict:mayavi

firstly, conda uninstall mayavi, and then conda install pandas=0.18.1, it works. Thanks!