# pd.read_csv ("file name.csv) fails to run

Tags: python, pandas, image, csv, import

My PD.read_csv in Pandas is not importing my .csv file for visual representation.It keeps returning an error message. What could be the problem?
I have tried

```
data=pd.read_csv('Sample-Spreadsheet-10-rows.csv' encoding = "utf-8")
print data.head
```

This code has refused to compile.

Comment: You're missing `,` before `encoding`. Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: You didn't think we'd need to know the error message?

Comment: there's a , before encoding  and the error message is UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1260/3138671198.py in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 data=pd.read_csv('Sample-Spreadsheet-10-rows.csv')
      3 print (data)

Answer (score 2):

Missing comma before encoding

```
data=pd.read_csv('Sample-Spreadsheet-10-rows.csv', encoding = "utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37136793/15809896 and follow the question and also the answer !